# How can I auto create arrays (and not objects) on my binded object using ng-model

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an app that looks like this:

```
angular.module('app',[]).
controller('ctrl', function(){
    this.model = { data: {} };
});
```

And an input that looks like this:

```
<input ng-model="vm.model.data.Name" />
```

Now even though my model's data doesn't have the Name property, it will be created on the fly as soon as I modify the input.

The same will happen with nested objects successfully:

```
<input ng-model="vm.model.data.Address.Addrline1" />
```

When I do the same with an array, then it doesn't identify that it's an array, but an object (since you can fetch a property like `obj["propName"]` and like `obj.propName`).

That means that this:

```
<input ng-model="vm.model.data.Drivers[0].Name" />
```

Will create this json:

```
"Drivers":{"0":{"Name":"name1"}}
```

And not the desired json:

```
"Drivers":[{"Name":"name1"}]
```

Is there any way I can force angular to create an array and not an object?

Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b3o0p7qa/) example - Fill the inputs and you will understand my question better.

Answer (score 1):

From your jsFiddle, I just needed to modify the stub definition to state that `Drivers` is expected to be an array:

```
angular.module('app',[]).
controller('ctrl', function(){
    this.model = {
        data:{
            Drivers: []
        }
    }
});
```

And then you get your desired output.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ccwmqpp/

This should work as long you expect there to be an array called `Drivers`

Comment: I wanted to achieve the creation without adding the Drivers to the data.

Comment: As you mention, Javascript uses the bracket notation for properties as well as arrays, so without anything forcing the creation of an array at any point, it will just treat `[0]` as a property accessor.

Comment: I understand that. I was looking for a different notation that ng-model would understand and treat the following as an array. I know that the odds are against me, but that's why stack over flow exists. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No worries, there's no other technique I'm aware of, angular still has to play by the rules of basic javascript when it comes to syntax